# Assigning list comprehension to an enum value

Tags: python, enums, pycharm, list-comprehension

While preparing some enums & pydantic models for a aws cdk project, I wondered why PyCharm has an issue with me assigning a list comprehensions like the one below to an enum value.

```py
class foo(Enum):
    bar = [str(v * 1024) for v in range(1, 3)]
```

PyCharm tells me: *Expected type 'int', got 'foo' instead*. I don't quite understand the issue here, since the code actually runs just fine and spits out the expected result, which is `["512", "1024", "2048"]`.

Yes, I could just build the list as a normal variable and reference it as the enum value, but I like avoid unnecessary variable declarations when coding.

Is it just not meant to be assigned like this or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:
for clarification: PyCharms TypeChecker marks the `v` in `str(v * 1024)` as a warning (yellow line, not red). There is NO ISSUE running the code!

EDIT2:
I'm specifically looking to create the cpu/memory-table shown at the bottom of [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-cpu-memory-error.html) as a python enum.

Comment: How is this gives you `"512"`?

Comment: Can you give us the call site? What line of code actually generates that error?

Comment: can not reproduce with `mypy` ... I get `Success: no issues found in 1 source file`

Comment: side-note: a list of strings is an unusual value for an enum - are you sure this is the representation you want ?

Comment: @Guy well it doesn't. thats was from an earlier version where I put `bar = ["512"] + [str(v * 1024) for v in range(1, 3)]`

Comment: @isaactfa I edited the original post for clarification on where the "issue" lies

Comment: @OrenIshShalom well I could just as well use a dict for this, but I prefer using enums for frequently accessed constants like these. This also makes sure, there are no spelling mistakes when accessing

Comment: If this list means something (I guess it does) I would put this in a `Final[Dict[str,List[str]]]` and let the str key describe the meaning of this list

Comment: As you noted, this is an issue with PyCharm -- non-`int` values are well supported by enums.  I would change one thing, though: use a `tuple` instead of a `list` for the values:  `bar = tuple([blah blah])` -- that way the values cannot be accidentally changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a way to create dynamic enums

```py
import enum
es = {}
for v in range(1, 3):
    es['n' + str(v * 1024)] = int(v * 1024)
foo  = enum.Enum('foo', es)
print(list(foo)) # this creates a dynamic enum
```

print
[image]

you can also access it via

```py
print(foo.n1024) # input
```

```py
foo.n1024; #ouptut
```

Comment: but the OP wants a list of strings ...

Comment: And there is no need to cast to `int` anyway.

Comment: @Guy i've made changes, please review

Comment: @OrenIshShalom i've made changes, please review

Comment: this would be somewhat applicable to what I'm trying to do, but might take tweaking. the base idea is definetly neat and something I didn't know was possible :) thanks!

Comment: This makes normal access impossible: `>>> foo.1024` --> `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: enums need to start with a letter

Comment: @EthanFurman see my edit, prefix the numbers with a letter, like `n` for example...

Comment: so `>>> foo.n1024` would be valid

Comment: Thank you for fixing that. Vote changed.

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen As Ethan pointed out, this is an issue with PyCharms TypeChecker.
I'll mark your answer as the solution, since its a nice workaround and solves the remaining part of the issue.